# Loop Invariants with Breaks

Tags: algorithm, clrs, loop-invariant

I am trying to understand how loop invariants interact with breaks. CLRS 3e (pg19) describes a loop invariant as requiring that

> If it is true before an iteration of the loop, it remains true before the next iteration.

So given the following trivial loop

```
for i = 1 to 5
    if i == 3 then break
```

Would it be fair to say that *i < 4* is an invariant property of the loop? The argument being that, since the loop terminates at the *break* statement, there is no iteration after that property is violated.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, that would be an invariant, for precisely the reason you’ve mentioned. Whether it’s a *useful* invariant is a separate question that depends on what you’re trying to prove.